# How to set all data of List<bool> to be false with some function

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

Anyone know how to set all data of `List<bool>` to be false?
Here is example:

```
List<bool> data = [true, false, true];

data = [false, false, false];
// output data = [false, false, false]
```

and there is my code to convert it, and i know that we can do with looping.
But here, i want to do with some function, which is i was tried with `data.every((element) => element = false);` but, that is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/List/fillRange.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to do something like this, here are a couple of them:

First, use the map method:

```
data = data.map<bool>((v) => false).toList();
```

The map method transforms every item on a list, we are using it like you wanted to use `every`

Second, use the filled method:

```
data = List.filled(data.length, false, growable: true);
```

The filled method makes a new list given a length and a value, in our case the length is the previous list length and the value is false.

Comment: what is growable?

Comment: growable determines weather or not you can add to the list, if you pass `growable: false`, and then you try to call `data.add(something)`, you get an error.

Comment: Also I think `growable: true` is the default, so even if you don't pass it and just do `List.filled(data.length, false)` your list will be growable ` @EkoMuhammadRiloPembudi

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [fillRange method for list](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/fillRange.html)
Here is the code you want:
**data.fillRange(0, data.length, false);**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the data variable the same, you could do this:

```
void main() {
  List<bool> data = [true, false, true];
  
  data.replaceRange(0, data.length, data.map((element) => false));
  
  print(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my three suggestions.

- reassign all false List
- loop each item and set to false
- use forEach

[image]

```
void main() {
  List<bool> data = [true, false, true];

  print('first origin data: $data');
  data = List<bool>.filled( data.length, false);
  print('first origin data: $data\n');
  
  
  data = [true, false, true];
  print('second origin data: $data');
  for (var loop = 0 ; loop < data.length ; loop++) {
    data[loop] = false;
  }
  print('second modified data: $data\n');
  
  data = [true, false, true];
  print('third origin data: $data');
  data.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
    if (value == true) {
      data[index] = false;
    }
  });
  print('third modified data: $data\n');
  
}
```